# Glassmapper and Media.RequestExtension Not Working Together

Tags: glass-mapper

I've got a Rich Text Field and using `glass mapper` to render the body field

```
[SitecoreField(I_HasPageContentConstants.BodyFieldName, Setting = SitecoreFieldSettings.RichTextRaw)]
string Body  {get; set;}

@Html.Glass().Editable(x => x.Body)
```

my rich text content is rendered however media that is embedded in the RTE content renders out with the `.ashx extension`.

Glassmapper doesn't seem to be using the `Media.RequestExtension setting`.

```
<!--  MEDIA - REQUEST EXTENSION
        The extension to use in media request URLs.
        If the value is not set, the Extension field of the individual media items will be used (ie. JPG, GIF, etc.)
        Default value: "ashx"
  -->
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="" />
```

I've tested rendering the field using Sitecore field rendering such as (below) and it works as expected.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Body")
```

Is there a way I can get `glass mapper` to render RTE content and correctly render linked media with the `Media.RequestExtension setting`?

using the following glass package

```
<package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc.101" version="5.8.180" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Comment: Could you please try removing `SitecoreFieldSettings.RichTextRaw` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will specify `SitecoreFieldSettings.RichTextRaw`, Sitecore will only call Render Field pipeline when rendering this field in edit mode. This means links within the field are not processed and converted when rendered on the front end. Links will have the default `.ashx` extension. To have links within your Rich Text fields to render with user-friendly URLs (not with the `.ashx` extension), the `setting Media.RequestExtension` needs to be blank (which you already not have) and your Rich Text fields **must not have** `SitecoreFieldSettings.RichTextRaw`.

```
[SitecoreField(I_HasPageContentConstants.BodyFieldName)]
string Body  {get; set;}
```

config setting -

```
<!--  MEDIA - REQUEST EXTENSION
    The extension to use in media request URLs.
    If the value is not set, the Extension field of the individual media items will be used (ie. JPG, GIF, etc.)
    Default value: "ashx"
 -->
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="" />
```